# Different char values require different sizes in file

Tags: c++, windows, newline, iostream, ofstream

I have this code snippet to write a buffer to a file

```
int WriteBufferToFile(std::string path, const char* buffer, int bufferSize) {
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open(path);

    if (!ofs) {
        return 1;
    }

    ofs.write(buffer, bufferSize);    

    if (!ofs) {
        return 2;
    }

    ofs.close();

    return 0;
}
```

## Case 1

```
std::vector<char> buffer(1000000, 0);

WriteBufferToFile("myRawData", buffer.data(), 1000000);
```

## Case 2

```
std::vector<char> buffer(1000000);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    buffer[i] = char(i);
}

WriteBufferToFile("myRawData2", buffer.data(), 1000000);
```

In Case 1 one I'm writing 1mb of just zeros to a file, which also will have 1mb in size, but in the second case i write arbitary chars (still should be 1mb in RAM) to a file, but now (in my tests it seems like especially when char's >= 10 are contained) the file size increases.

[image]

Why is that, and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How doesn't it seem to be the case? How are you checking? (And why do you think there would be headers or "escaping characters" in the file?)

Comment: How do you change the `100` to `10000000`? The number does not fit into a `char`.

Comment: I updated the question with an example.

Comment: I can't reproduce, the file takes exactly 100 bytes in my test, as expected.

Comment: @T.Grumser How do you measure the file size?

Comment: Added a picutre of my file system.

Comment: `of my file system` your file system uses compression to reduce file size

Comment: @KamilCuk: no, it doesn't unless explicitly enabled and it would be indicated by two little blue arrows on the file icon

Comment: @KamilCuk even a transparently compressed file on Windows won't show the compressed size just like on Linux. The file size shown is real size

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that you're running this code on a Windows system.

Here's what I think is probably happening.

`ofs.open(path)` is opening the file in text mode. On Windows, text mode means that every newline character (1 byte) will be replaced by a CRLF sequence (2 bytes). Your buffer contains 1 million characters which are filled with the values 0 to 999999 modulo 256. So 1 on 256 characters (3906 to be exact) will be replaced by a 2 byte sequence which accounts for the file size difference.

To fix this, open the file in binary mode:

```
ofs.open(path, ios_base::out | ios_base::binary)
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be on Windows. It looks like the C++ runtime rewrites 1-byte linebreak characters `'\n'` to the windows style 2-byte sequence `"\r\n"`. Therefore, you have about 1000000/256=3906.25 additional bytes in the file.